# Meteor 1.4.1.1 how installing react and kadira:react-layout?

Tags: javascript, meteor, react-native, kadira

i'm trying installing packages of react  but the console log return this
the same issue when i trying installing kadira:react-layout. How can I fix it?

`I20160915-17:27:56.255(2)? [Error: Can't find npm module 'react-addons-transition-group/package.json'. Did you forget to call 'Npm.depends' in package.js within the 'modules-runtime' package?]
I20160915-17:27:56.257(2)? [Error: Can't find npm module 'react-addons-css-transition-group/package.json'. Did you forget to call 'Npm.depends' in package.js within the 'modules-runtime' package?]
I20160915-17:27:56.258(2)? [Error: Can't find npm module 'react-addons-linked-state-mixin/package.json'. Did you forget to call 'Npm.depends' in package.js within the 'modules-runtime' package?]
I20160915-17:27:56.259(2)? [Error: Can't find npm module 'react-addons-create-fragment/package.json'. Did you forget to call 'Npm.depends' in package.js within the 'modules-runtime' package?]
I20160915-17:27:56.260(2)? [Error: Can't find npm module 'react-addons-update/package.json'. Did you forget to call 'Npm.depends' in package.js within the 'modules-runtime' package?]
I20160915-17:27:56.260(2)? [Error: Can't find npm module 'react-addons-pure-render-mixin/package.json'. Did you forget to call 'Npm.depends' in package.js within the 'modules-runtime' package?]
I20160915-17:27:56.261(2)? [Error: Can't find npm module 'react-addons-test-utils/package.json'. Did you forget to call 'Npm.depends' in package.js within the 'modules-runtime' package?]
I20160915-17:27:56.262(2)? [Error: Can't find npm module 'react-addons-perf/package.json'. Did you forget to call 'Npm.depends' in package.js within the 'modules-runtime' package?]
W20160915-17:27:56.263(2)? (STDERR) WARNING: npm peer requirements (for react-runtime) not installed:
W20160915-17:27:56.264(2)? (STDERR)  - react-addons-transition-group@15.x not installed.
W20160915-17:27:56.264(2)? (STDERR)  - react-addons-css-transition-group@15.x not installed.
W20160915-17:27:56.264(2)? (STDERR)  - react-addons-linked-state-mixin@15.x not installed.
W20160915-17:27:56.265(2)? (STDERR)  - react-addons-create-fragment@15.x not installed.
W20160915-17:27:56.265(2)? (STDERR)  - react-addons-update@15.x not installed.
W20160915-17:27:56.266(2)? (STDERR)  - react-addons-pure-render-mixin@15.x not installed.
W20160915-17:27:56.266(2)? (STDERR)  - react-addons-test-utils@15.x not installed.
W20160915-17:27:56.266(2)? (STDERR)  - react-addons-perf@15.x not installed.
W20160915-17:27:56.266(2)? (STDERR) 
W20160915-17:27:56.267(2)? (STDERR) Read more about installing npm peer dependencies:
W20160915-17:27:56.267(2)? (STDERR)   http://guide.meteor.com/using-packages.html#peer-npm-dependencies
W20160915-17:27:56.267(2)? (STDERR) 
W20160915-17:27:56.513(2)? (STDERR) /Users/ortiz/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.1_1.1h0re2h++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280
W20160915-17:27:56.514(2)? (STDERR)                         throw(ex);
W20160915-17:27:56.514(2)? (STDERR)                         ^
W20160915-17:27:56.514(2)? (STDERR) 
W20160915-17:27:56.515(2)? (STDERR) Error: Can't find npm module 'react-addons-transition-group'. Did you forget to call 'Npm.depends' in package.js within the 'modules-runtime' package?
W20160915-17:27:56.515(2)? (STDERR)     at Object.Npm.require (/Users/ortiz/Siti/tutorial/meteor/react/flowrouter/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:198:17)
W20160915-17:27:56.515(2)? (STDERR)     at options.fallback (packages/modules-runtime/modules-runtime.js:21:1)
W20160915-17:27:56.515(2)? (STDERR)     at require (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:88:1)
W20160915-17:27:56.516(2)? (STDERR)     at meteorInstall.node_modules.meteor.react-runtime.react-runtime.js (packages/react-runtime/react-runtime.js:29:20)
W20160915-17:27:56.517(2)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:153:1)
W20160915-17:27:56.517(2)? (STDERR)     at require (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:82:1)
W20160915-17:27:56.517(2)? (STDERR)     at /Users/ortiz/Siti/tutorial/meteor/react/flowrouter/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/react-runtime.js:79:15
W20160915-17:27:56.517(2)? (STDERR)     at /Users/ortiz/Siti/tutorial/meteor/react/flowrouter/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/react-runtime.js:92:3
W20160915-17:27:56.517(2)? (STDERR)     at /Users/ortiz/Siti/tutorial/meteor/react/flowrouter/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:292:10
W20160915-17:27:56.518(2)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
=> Exited with code: 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install follow packages from react to fix the issue.

- react-addons-create-fragment
- react-addons-css-transition-group
- react-addons-linked-state-mixin
- react-addons-perf
- react-addons-pure-render-mixin
- react-addons-test-utils
- react-addons-transition-group
- react-addons-update
- react-dom

You can just run the following command to fix the issue.

```
meteor npm install --save react-addons-create-fragment react-addons-css-transition-group react-addons-linked-state-mixin react-addons-perf react-addons-pure-render-mixin react-addons-test-utils react-addons-transition-group react-addons-update react-dom
```

Comment: '-' is missing in 'react-addons-css transition-group' ,please edit it.